# Is there any way to make a command in discord js that allows the user to choose an image (image path from local) and send it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been looking up how to send an image with a bot command and only found how to send the same image from the repo of the project or a static URL, but I didn't see how to make a command that allows the user to choose an image and send it.
I need this feature to make a bot command that sends an announcement in a specific channel, and including an image in that announcement should be optional.

I've tried this:

```js
async execute(interaction) {
    if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "admin")) {
        await interaction.reply(`You don't have access !`);
        return;
    } else {
        const { MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
        //extracting the image path
        const image_path = interaction.options.getString("image_path");
        const file = new MessageAttachment(image_path);
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("Announcement image").setImage(image_path);
        //converting the msg to string
        const message = interaction.options.getString("message");
        await interaction.reply(`${message} message sent !`);
        channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed], files: [file] });
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: I found out that slash commands don't support embeds and images as arguments, you can collect them in another channel in a collection and send them back in a timestamp that you can specify